# Cannot get .Net Framework 4.8 to install on Windows Server 2012 Standard

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, installation, windows-server-2012

I am currently running .Net Framework 4.7.03062 on my Windows 2012 Server. I ran the Offline installation of Version 4.8. It finished and said that version 4.8 was installed. When I look at the registry, .Net Framework 4.7.03062 is still the current version.

I have tried the web install of 4.8. I have run the DotNetrepair tool. I have run sfc /scannow to repair files. NOTHING has worked. During the install, there is a list of services that use .net, I have opened the services console and stopped all of them before running the installation. It still does not install. There is NO error message to indicate the problem. I know that Server 2012 standard is supported in .Net Framework 4.8 but not version 4.8.1. We are also running SQL server 2008 on this machine. Could there be a compatibility issue with the SQL server?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right place? Check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed